# Populating select option bug Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a school management system and after working on all the bugs this is the one I can't seem to fix!
In my system you can select from a drop down, the Parents of the child (Father and Mother), the information saves into the db correctly but upon editing/viewing there is an issue.

After you close the modal for the first child and move onto the 2nd and then back to the first the father and mother show the previous child's parental data.

I have tried clearing the value of the select/ unselecting the drop down prior to it being populated by ajax but to no avail. 
Here is the code and it only executes whenever you select the edit button on the childs row:

```
$.ajax({
            url: base_url + 'student/fetchStudentData/'+studentId,
            type: 'post',
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success:function(response){

                // UNSELECT THE DROP DOWNS TO RESET             
                //$('#editSex').find("option:selected").prop('selected',false);
                //$('#editFatherId').find("option:selected").prop('selected',false);
                //$('#editMotherId').find("option:selected").prop('selected',false);

                $("#editFname").val(response.fname);
                $("#editLname").val(response.lname);
                $("#editDob").val(response.dob);

                // NOW SELECT THE OPTION
                $('#editSex option[value='+ response.sex +']').attr('selected','selected');
                $('#editFatherId option[value='+ response.father_id +']').attr('selected','selected');
                $('#editMotherId option[value='+ response.mother_id +']').attr('selected','selected');

                $("#editAge").val(response.age);
                $("#editContact").val(response.contact);
                $("#editEmail").val(response.email);
                $("#editAddress").val(response.address);
                $("#editCity").val(response.city);
                $("#editCountry").val(response.country);
                $("#editRegisterDate").val(response.register_date);
                $("#editClassName").val(response.class_id);

                $("#editSectionName").load('student/fetchClassSection/'+response.class_id, function(i) {
                    $("#editSectionName").val(response.section_id);
                });             

                $("#student_photo").attr('src', base_url + response.image);

                $("#editClassName").unbind('change').bind('change', function() {
                    var class_id = $(this).val();
                    $("#editSectionName").load('student/fetchClassSection/'+class_id);
                });
```

HTML AND PHP:

```
        <!-- FATHER -->
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="editFatherId" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Father</label>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            <select class="form-control" name="editFatherId" id="editFatherId">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <?php foreach ($parentsDataMale as $key => $value) { ?>
              <option value="<?php echo $value['parents_id'] ?>"><?php echo $value['fname'] . ' ' . $value['lname'] ?></option>
            <?php } // /forwach ?>
          </select>
          </div>                  
        </div>

        <!-- MOTHER -->
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="editMotherId" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Mother</label>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            <select class="form-control" name="editMotherId" id="editMotherId">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <?php foreach ($parentsDataFemale as $key => $value) { ?>
              <option value="<?php echo $value['parents_id'] ?>"><?php echo $value['fname'] . ' ' . $value['lname'] ?></option>
            <?php } // /forwach ?>
          </select>
          </div>                  
        </div>
```

IMAGES OF ISSUE:
FIRST CHILD:
[image: Child 1 Edit]

SECOND CHILD:
[image: Child 2 Data]

BACK TO FIRST:
[image: Back to Child 1]

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/) of your problem

Comment: I have edited the question. Thanks

Comment: Where are you populating the select elements like `#editSex, #editLname and #editMotherId` ?

Comment: Are that already populated and you are just selecting the values coming from database or you are populating them as well?

Comment: The only thing I can imagine - or better guess - from your question (the HTML source of the forms would be good) is that when you set the values using jQuery selectors, it could be that more than one form element matches the selector. That is, `$("#editAge").val(response.age)` sets the value for **all** form elements that have the ID editAge. I suppose you have multiple form elements with the same ID.

Comment: the information is being populated via PHP, the data array provides the dropdown list, im just using JS to select the option received from AJAX

Comment: @TheCoprolal I thought that to, but I can view any amount of records and the data is correct, but once I go back to a childs information more than once, it just shows the previous childs information from there on in

Comment: That isn't a MCVE. We need full recreation steps, so your HTML, etc. The block of code you've added is only marginally helpful. An imagine of your HTML doesn't help at all

Comment: @Liam i've added the HTML

Comment: Ok, last time, please read the [link I've posted](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/) as well as this one [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You need to put enough code into the question so that we can verify your problem and **reproduce it**. Otherwise we're all just guessing. This doesn't help you or us. We can't reproduce your problem based on what you've posted. Create a fully working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ I'd guess that when you do this it'll either work or you'll spot your problem yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should "deselect" all options before "selecting" one using the json data. Else, you risk having more than one selected... And that's odd.

Also, use the boolean property instead of playing with the attribute.

```
// NOW SELECT THE OPTION
$('#editSex option').prop('selected',false);
$('#editSex option[value='+ response.sex +']').prop('selected',true);
$('#editFatherId option').prop('selected',false);
$('#editFatherId option[value='+ response.father_id +']').prop('selected',true);
$('#editMotherId option').prop('selected',false);
$('#editMotherId option[value='+ response.mother_id +']').prop('selected',true);
```

Comment: Hey thumbs up your answer solved the issue, It was close to what I was doing, thanks for all the help. Between yo, Mohammed and Liam, you resolved my issues. Sorry for not so being helpful in my question!

Comment: That wasn't a behavior easy to explain... Happy it helped.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using

```
 $('#editSex option[value='+ response.sex +']').attr('selected','selected');
 $('#editFatherId option[value='+ response.father_id +']').attr('selected','selected');
 $('#editMotherId option[value='+ response.mother_id +']').attr('selected','selected');
```

Try

```
$('#editSex').val(response.sex);
$('#editFatherId ').val(response.father_id );
$('#editMotherId ').val(response.mother_id );
```

If you want to use what you are already using, try using prop to `true`

```
    $('#editSex option[value='+ response.sex +']').prop('selected',true);
    $('#editFatherId option[value='+ response.father_id +']').prop('selected',true);
    $('#editMotherId option[value='+ response.mother_id +']').prop('selected',true);
```